# kill a group of processes with negative PID

Tags: process, kill, process-groups

```
kill -TERM -PID
```

is supposed to kill PID and all its child processes.
but this doesn't work on openSUSE, it always tell me that no such process -PID no matter what PID i use.
So if the negative PID option is not supported by this particular version of kill, what is the best way to kill a group of processes?

background:
I have a shell script running. inside the script, I use wget to download things. So the script is the parent process, wget is the child process. I want to kill them both using kill -TERM -PID_OF_SCRIPT

Comment: Quoting the [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/kill.html#tag_20_64_05): *If the first pid operand is negative, it **should be preceded by "--"** to keep it from being interpreted as an option*. Also, using a negative number for the `pid` arg actually **refers to the *process group ID***.

Comment: It's not supposed to _kill PID and all its child processes_, it's supposed to kill all the processes of pgid `PID`. Use `ps -j` to see the process group ids.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Does it say "no such PID" or is there an error, - as in does this work?

```
kill -TERM -- -GPID
```

Also note, as per (emphasize mine)
[man 1](http://linux.die.net/man/1/kill):

> *"[…] When an argument of the form '-n' is given, and it is meant to denote a **process group** […]"*

[man 2](http://linux.die.net/man/2/kill):

> *"[…] If pid is less than -1, then sig is sent to every process in the **process group whose ID is -pid.** […]"*

[man 3](http://linux.die.net/man/3/kill):

> *"[…] If pid is negative, but not -1, sig shall be sent to all processes (excluding an unspecified set of system processes) whose **process group ID** is equal to the absolute value of pid, […]"*

As in, not PID but process group ID.

---

Else perhaps you can have so fun with [/proc/[pid]/stat](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)

```
ppid: awk '{gsub(/\([^)]+\)/,"_"); print $4}' /proc/3955/stat
pgrp: awk '{gsub(/\([^)]+\)/,"_"); print $5}' /proc/3955/stat
```

pkill -TERM -g PGRP

Comment: it says /bin/kill: -23958: No such process.

Comment: pkill -TERM -g PGRP, this works perfectly in my case.

Comment: what does `kill --` do?

Comment: @Zibri usually (by convention) a single argument of `--` stops the processing of "options" and reads all words after the `--` as "arguments." For example, to remove a file that is called `-r` you cannot use `rm -r`, you need to write `rm -- -r`. I assume this is the same with kill. If you need to kill the *process group id* 9, you will have to write `kill -- -9` because `kill -9` treats the number as an option (the signal to use) instead of an argument (the process or group id to kill.)

Answer (score 6):

The error message `/bin/kill: -23958: No such process` may also be due to the fact that the pid `23958` is **no** pgid (process group id number)!

This can, for example, be the case if you try to kill a backgrounded shell (or command) in a script mistakenly using `$!` as a pgid; in a job-control enabled shell, however, `$!` can be used as a pgid (see: [Why child process still alive after parent process was killed in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20888200)).

```
# examples of how to kill a process group
# (using sh -c '...' instead of a shell script)

# kill: -<num>: No such process
sh -c '
(sleep 200 & sleep 200 & sleep 200) &
/bin/kill -s TERM -$!
'

# in Terminal.app 
# job control is enabled by default
(sleep 200 & sleep 200 & sleep 200) &
/bin/kill -s TERM -$!


# enable job control
sh -c '
set -m 
(sleep 200 & sleep 200 & sleep 200) &
/bin/kill -s TERM -$!
'

# make sure pid == pgid
# note that the script gets killed as well
sh -c '
echo pid $$
trap "trap - EXIT; echo pid $$ was killed" EXIT
(sleep 200 & sleep 200 & sleep 200) &
IFS=" " read -r pgid <<EOF
$(ps -p $! -o pgid=)
EOF
sleep 5
/bin/kill -s TERM -${pgid}
sleep 5
echo pid $$ was not killed
'

# use a pseudo-terminal (pty) to avoid killing the script
# note the use of -$$ instead of -$!
sh -c '
echo pid $$
script -q /dev/null sh -c '\''
trap "" HUP
(sleep 200 & sleep 200 & sleep 200) &
sleep 5
/bin/kill -s TERM -$$
'\''
sleep 5
echo pid $$ was not killed
'
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the "pkill" or the "killtree" solution, shown on this thread on other of the StackExchange sites :)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392022/best-way-to-kill-all-child-processes

```
pkill -TERM -P PARENT_PID
```

Answer (score 2):

This may have to do with you using the shell built-in kill and not the binary, try to use

```
/bin/kill
```

If it works I would suggest to check if your shell has added the process group feature to a newer version. Or just use the binary.

Comment: I thought about that. And I tried /bin/kill, it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

if the underlying OS uses Busybox and thus, says `Error: kill: bad signal name '-'`, it's most probably an issue with `--`.

You need to specify `kill -TERM -- -[gpid]` instead of just `kill -- -[gpid]`. TERM is the default signal.

I dont know why.